# test the internal validity of this model / score by Resampling by Bootstraping

Tags: regression, logistic, prediction, bootstrap

I am working on a predictive model of a diagnosis via a logistic regression "glm"
Let me clarify right away, I am a medical doctor and researcher, not a mathematician, so sorry if I use terms that lack precision / accuracy.

I initially identified 2 biomarkers very associated with the desired diagnosis (varExplicative1 & varExplicative2). So I made ROC curves, ..., defined thresholds, binarized the 2 biomarkers, and created a predictive score from the coefficients of these biomarkers from the regression model.
It is therefore a score constructed to be a screening / exclusion score, so as not to carry out the imaging procedure necessary to make this diagnosis.
This score obtains a sensitivity of 95% (95% CI 93-99), and a NPV of 92% (75-99).

This is what the dataset limited to these 3 variables looks like :

```
head(XX, 5)

  clin_diag score_ddi_etev score_leuco_etev
1  etev_pos         >=3000             >=12
2  etev_pos         >=3000              <12
3  etev_pos         >=3000              <12
4  etev_pos          <3000             >=12
5  etev_pos         >=3000             >=12
```

Logistic regression: creation of the model :

```
glm_mod <- glm(clin_diag ~  score_ddi_etev + score_leuco_etev, family = binomial, data = XX) 
summary(glm_mod)$coefficients

                      Estimate Std. Error   z value     Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)          -2.219552  0.6223875 -3.566190 3.622094e-04
score_ddi_etev>=3000  3.199800  0.7350007  4.353466 1.340019e-05
score_leuco_etev>=12  2.679261  0.9645409  2.777758 5.473535e-03
```

The sample being small (n = 72), I therefore built the model on the whole sample (n = 72)
My question: I would like to test the internal validity of this model / score by Resampling by Bootstraping.

I read the doc on the "boot" package. but I don't know how to apply it to R. In particular the function to be entered in "statistic"

Can you help me ? As well as the interpretation of the response of R

My essay :

```
# Function #
????

# Resampling#
b <-  boot(data = XX, statistic=regLog, R=2000, sim="ordinary", stype="i") 
summary(b)
```

Thank you a lot